# Why Visual studio 2017 preview freezes at a certain point while coding

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have installed **visual studio 2017 preview** on my PC, **core i7 , 8gb RAM**. but when am coding in python (flask) it slows down. Is there any clue on how to stabilize it.

I wanted to develop python projects in visual studio 2017 and i saw the preview one. but it has the issue above.

Comment: might help https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/228256/vs-2017-preview-freezes.html

Comment: @Prany, the link didn't help but thanks

Comment: vs preview is nice in python development but that bug of freezing has to be catered for.